# MQ initial context class in MQ series 9

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have JNDI context in MQ queue manager, my standalone java client is able to do lookup, with initial context class, `com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory`, it is working with MQ client jars for versions before MQ 8. It also has the `mqcontext.jar` in my classpath.

With MQ 8 and 9, I am trying to use the relocatable jars `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and `com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar` in my classpath and the JNDI lookup is failing. If I add the old `mqcontext.jar` to classpath, I get below error.

```
 javax.naming.NamingException: Caught an MQ Exception: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageFormatException: JMSCC0053: An exception occurred deserializing a message, exception: 'java.io.InvalidClassException: com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.WMQConnectionName; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3226780381239434112, local class serialVersionUID = -2174857328193645055'.
```

Comment: Did the answer help?  If not let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: please i can't find com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory anywhere, I'm using IBM MQ version 7.5.0.1, where could i find it or find mqcontext.jar?

Answer (score 0):

For **IBM MQ Classes for JMS** you can find the list of files required on the Knowledge Center page "[What is installed for IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031540_.htm)":

> **Relocatable JAR files**
>   Within an enterprise, the following files can be moved to systems that need to run IBM MQ classes for JMS:
>
> - com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
> - com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
> - jms.jar
> - fscontext.jar
> - providerutil.jar

Answer (score 0):

> com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory

I would strongly recommend you not use the MQ queue manager as the resource holder for MQ JNDI.  You should either use file based MQ JNDI or LDAP based MQ JNDI.

The last time I checked, using WMQInitialContextFactory would not allow the use of either MQ client-side security exit and/or TLS/SSL.  Hence, you have to connect to the queue manager without any security.  Bad, bad idea.

With hacks taking place everyday and private/confidential information getting dumped to the web and/or dark web, EVERY queue manager should be locked down tight.

Comment: Thanks Roger. Unfortunately, I am not the decision maker at the place I work. I solved the issue, by using the old MQ 7 jars for now.